# activity's life cycle is beyond its application process?

Tags: android, android-activity

I got a main-activity, then it opened a new-activity. After putting it to background by clicking home button. If I killed the process using adb shell commands, then I reopen my app.

The new-activity is shown by default instead of starting from the first activity.

My question is that activity's life cycle is beyond its application process? 
As the sample shows, even activity's application process is killed, the saved activity still is there. Is this correct? And will android system recycle the saved activities later?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html. did you check the docs?

Answer (score 0):

If you reopen the app via the activities list, it will attempt to restart via the last open activity.  It's a "feature" of Android that can be incredibly annoying (and frequently just wrong)-  Android assumes every app can serialize its entire state when exited for later reopening.  You either need to do that (via onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState) or you need to catch when you're relaunched and explicity launch your main activity.

This shouldn't happen if you're relaunched via the app launcher, as that should always launch your specified activity.

Comment: Gabe, I am a newbie for android. what do you mean reopen app via activities list or app launcher? How to invoke them? thanks.

Comment: The launcher is the big list of all apps on the phone.  You get there by tapping on the apps icon.  The list of activities is the list of running activities- you get there by long pressing home or pressing the activites button depending on your hardware.

Comment: This answer is not correct. If you have an app with 2 activities, and you launch activity A and then activity B, and then press the HOME button, your task with both activities is put in the background. If you then click on the app icon to "relaunch" the app, it will just bring the existing task (containing the 2 activities) to the front. That's the standard, default behaviour. You can adjust this behaviour using launch modes and intent flags and such, but usually this creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @DavidWasser, while that's true, we're talking about actually killing the app first. In that, Gabe is correct that the tasks list will relaunch the full task with its activities stack.

In general, it's easier to just implement proper state serialization than to fight all the corner cases where Android tries to restore your activities..

Comment: You wrote **"This shouldn't happen if you're relaunched via the app launcher, as that should always launch your specified activity."**. This is incorrect.

Comment: Like Delyan said-  we were talking in the context of the application having been killed.  In this case I am correct.  If the application was not killed then it will bring the still running app to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Android remembers the state of recent tasks and activities. Android can kill your application's process at any time (if it is in the background). If your application was killed while in the background, Android remembers what activities were in the task and how they were started (Intents). If the user now returns to the task (either by selecting from the list of recent tasks, or by tapping the application's icon in the list of applications), Android will create a new process for the task and recreate the activity that was on the **top of the stack** (ie: the activity that was in front when the task was sent to the background). This allows users to open an applicaton, use it, leave it to do something else, and then return to the application where they left off.

In order for this to work properly, you must save and restore any necessary state (using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

If a task goes to the background and is idle (unused) for some period of time (device manufacturers can change this, usually the value is something like 30 or 60 minutes), Android will **reset the task**. In this case, if the user returns to the task, the previous saved state will be ignored and the user will start from the beginning. However you can prevent this from happening by setting `alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` on the root (starting) activity.